# Prove $\lim_{x\to3} \frac{2x+3}{4x-9}=3$ using $\epsilon-\delta$ definition

Tags: limits, epsilon-delta

(This is an old question, but I still have some doubts on $\delta$)

To prove that $\lim_{x\to3} \frac{2x+3}{4x-9}=3$, I can find an appropriate $\delta$ ($\delta = \dfrac{\epsilon}{10}$) when $|4x-9|>1$, since:

$$ 10\dfrac{|x-3|}{|4x-9|}<\dfrac{\epsilon}{|4x-9|}< \epsilon.$$

However, I don't know how to proceed when $|4x-9|\le1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that for $x$ close to $2.25$ you get into trouble. To avoid this, the standard approach is to declare that no matter what, you will *never* pick $\delta$ to be larger than $\frac12$ (not that there is anything special with $\frac12$; any value below $\frac34$ will work). With this in mind, you only have to care about $x$ between $2.5$ and $3.5$.

On this interval we have $|4x-9|>1$, so
$$
\left|\frac{2x+3}{4x-9}-3\right|=\left|\frac{-10x+30}{4x-9}\right|<10|x-3|
$$
If we want the left-hand side to be less than some given $\varepsilon>0$, it's easy to see that it's enough to pick $\delta=\frac{\varepsilon}{10}$.

Thus our final choice for $\delta$ is
$$
\delta=\min\left(\frac12, \frac{\varepsilon}{10}\right)
$$

Comment: Thank you. So to summarize, we want first of all to pick a $\delta$ s.t. $|4x-9|>1$ is always satisfied. In this way, for $\delta<\frac{\epsilon}{10}<\epsilon$ we are good by construction, and when $\delta>\frac{\epsilon}{10}$, $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{10}$ is good as well. Is this reasoning correct?

Comment: @pdb When $\varepsilon<5$, then $\delta=\varepsilon/10$ works fine. When $\varepsilon\geq5$, then $\delta=\frac12$ works. This is what my answer says (except I didn't bother to explicitly figure out that $\varepsilon=5$ is the "critical" value here). We could've conspired to pick a $\delta$ such that $|4x-9|>43$ always holds instead, if we wanted to. Or $|4x-9|>10^{-192}$. As I said, there is nothing really special about $\frac12$.

Comment: Ok. Still, we want $\delta<0.75$ to avoid that $x \in[2,2.25]$?

Comment: @pdb Yes, we still want that. Specifically, we want to make sure that there is some bound how close to $2.25$ that $x$ can get, so that there is some bound on how close to $0$ that $4x-9$ can get. Technically the would be nothing wrong with $x=2.1$ in and of itself, but that's on the far side of $2.25$, so we can't let it happen.